# WPF - Binding Textbox Text to a class property

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, textbox

I am doing some changes in my WPF project to make it less deprecated. 
One of the things I am trying to do is Binding my `Textbox.Text` value to a simple **Class** as shown below.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtNCM"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="5"
         MaxLength="8"
         Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
</TextBox>
```

```c#
public partial class wCad_NCM : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public wCad_NCM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

Everytime I use the Immediate Window to display the Name's value, it is shown as **null**. I am really new to this, so I had to search for a similar situation to adapt, but I don't know how to make this work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `DataContext` and give `Name` a value.

To do that, change your constructor to include this:

```
public wCad_NCM()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; // Sets the DataContext
    Name = "Test";
}
```

This should make it work, but is typically bad practice. See http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html for more details.

Additionally, I tried running this and ran into a name hiding problem. Try using a variable name other than `Name` as `FrameworkElement` already contains it.